# Thread.CurrentPrincipal Vs HttpContext.User Vs ServiceSecurityContext.Current

Tags: asp.net, wcf

Could some please provide clear and concise explanations with examples on the differences between Thread.CurrentPrincipal, HttpContext.User and ServiceSecurityContext.Current? Also, what are the scenarios where each of them are used (and others cannot be used)?

Thanks!